Show the macOS "... would like to access data from other apps." dialog again after it has been rejected
I have a macOS non-sandboxed app written in Swift + SwiftUI. The app needs to access data from a different application's container. When I try to access such data, it shows the classic ""app" would like to access data from other apps." dialog: 
If the user clicks the "Don't Allow" button, Swift throws the fileWriteNoPermission Cocoa error.  After handling this error, I would like to explain the reasoning behind the access requirement and ask the user to allow it (by clicking on a "Try again" button and re-displaying the system dialog). Unfortunately, I have not found a way to display that dialog again without restarting the application - the first rejection is remembered until the process restarts. My question is: Is it (programmatically) possible to invalidate the user's previous decision and show the dialog again, so the user can change the previous decision and grant access?
